# Not allowed to enumerate cross origin objects - for(i in x) in array of objects

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

This I don't understand. I made a simple recursive function to search in whatever object I pass to it.
It works as I expect unless I try to give it an array (or object) of window properties as the first parameter.

```
window.search_object([window.API, window.Chat], /vote/);  //Error: Not allowed to enumerate cross origin objects
window.search_object({x:window.API, y:window.Chat}, /vote/);  //Error: Not allowed to enumerate cross origin objects
```

The error occurs on line with `for(var i in object)`.

#### The object search function:

```
window.search_object = function(object, search_string, max_recursion, search_value, history, path) {
    //This will be returned in the end
    var results = [];
    //Just ignore document object
    if(object == window.document)
      return [];
    //Only created in level 1 function, others get this passed by parameter
    if(history==null)
      history = {data:[]};
    //Simplest way to find the origin of found values
    if(path==null)
      path = [];
    //Convert sring to regext (I'm lazy)
    if(typeof search_string=="string") {
      search_string = new RegExp(search_string);
    }        
    //Some errors
    if(!(search_string instanceof window.RegExp)) {
      console.log([search_string, search_string instanceof window.RegExp])
      throw new Error("search_object() -> Parameter 2 (searched string) must be a string or RegExp object.");    
    }
    if(typeof object != "object") {
      throw new Error("search_object() -> Parameter 1 (object to search in) must be a Javascript object");    
    }
    //Loop
    for(var i in object) {   //<-------THIS IS THE ERROR LINE
        //Test if the property name matches
        if(search_string.test(i)) {
          //Add in results (no duplicate fallback here)
          results.push([object[i], path.concat(i)]);
        }
        //Recursion
        if(typeof object[i]=="object") {
          //Check if we did not parse this object already
          if(history.data.find(object[i])===false) {
            //Remember the object
            history.data.push(object[i]);
            //Add results from all sub-objects
            results = results.concat(window.search_object(object[i], search_string, null, null, history, path.concat(i)));
          }
        }
    }
    //console.log(results);
    return results;
}

Array.prototype.find = function(needle) {
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
       if(this[i]==needle)
         return i;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are aware of the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)?

Comment: How could I break this in this case?

Comment: Please check this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy/3076648#3076648), maybe you can find your answer...

Comment: Please take a note that I am, in fact, not looping through `window` object - non of the objects I pass as argument leave any refference back to window object (as far as I know). And, again, the error is thrown before the `for` loop starts. I see no way the script could access different frames contained in window.

Comment: What is `API`? What is `Chat`?

Comment: Some objects with huge structure. Is there anything they should countain to make it matter what they are? I have a suspition that they cause the error, yet it cannot be the any of errors meant so far. Finding the issue in them will not be easy since these are the obejct I actually wanted to search in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window object has circular references.  This will cause a -- wait for it -- a stack overflow.

Comment: What is circular reference? I have a recursion fallback (I never parse one object twice). The error is thrown before the loop even starts.

Comment: @TomášZato See the [Wikipedia circular reference article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference#In_computer_programming)

Comment: This has no relation to my problem. The function **will not loop one object twice** (I've tested this on dummy objects!). Also, the object I pass in the array do **not contain any refference to window object**.